# rvm conflit with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

$: /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
    ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

```
Abort trap
```

It's seem that ruby is not the correct version (1.8.7) but :

```
$: ruby - v
$: ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-15 revision 28653) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]



$: gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
actionpack (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
activemodel (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
activerecord (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
activeresource (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
activesupport (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
arel (0.4.0, 0.3.3)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (0.9.26)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.4.1, 0.3.7)
mail (2.2.5)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.9)
rack-test (0.5.4)
rails (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
railties (3.0.0.beta4, 3.0.0.beta3)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.9)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
thor (0.13.8)
treetop (1.4.8)
tzinfo (0.3.22)
will_paginate (3.0.pre)
```

more info :

```
$: ~ dev$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-15 revision 28653) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
$ :~ dev$ rails -v



/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how this has happened in your case but it looks to me that Rails has tried to run with your system installed Ruby but is loading gems from a 1.9.2 load path. Very odd.

You see the correct Ruby version in your shell (RVM has precedence in the local path) but that's not apparently what Rails is being started with.

Check to see you how you are starting Rails and that you don't have paths or links or aliases messed up between Ruby versions

Answer (score 22):

Had the same issue after moving to 1.9.2p0, but restarting the console on Snow Leopard did the trick. Seems rvm might have gotten confused.

Comment: Had this issue when adding and removing .rmvc files, restarting the console worked, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

<del>Same problem for me on Snow Leopard; even though under rvm 1.9.2@rails3, I can see correct rails version number.</del>

<del>I have to use following command to use rails command:</del>

<del>`ruby` `which rails` `g scaffold User name:string bio:text`</del>

<del>Any solution?</del>

I've finally found the reason. Looks like `gem install rails` is not managed to install the proper binary for rails in rvm. And `rails` is still references `/usr/bin/rails`, which have a `#!` line point to System ruby.

You can see it with:

```
head -1 `which rails`
```

which returns:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

Change that to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

will fix the problem. I don't know if this problem affect other executable scripts gem installs, but why gem not install rails to rvm's own bin path is a mystery to me. Anyway, this workaround do the dirty for me.

Comment: I had the same issue.  I created the rails application using system gems and ruby and then entered the rails app and created an .rvmrc.  I believe this is how my issue arose.

Comment: This fixed my issue from the command line. However, I did have to restart textmate to allow the change to be picked up from there.

Comment: This precisely is what's happening. I have two versions of rails on my server:  that which came from Apple and the latest version supplied by the Homebrew team.

Answer (score 5):

I Had the same problem when using ree-1.8.7-2011.03.  (Ruby enterprise Edition)

I uninstalled the sqlite3 gems then I ran:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

and it worked.  Note that the sqlite3-ruby gem now recommends to use 'sqlite3' now.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to run

```
rvm reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem after a bunch of updates (rvm to 1.5.2 and ruby to 1.9.2-p180)

Console restart did not work for me, updating to rails 3.0.6 changed the error to a seg error of mysql2 instead of sqlite3, re-installing mysql2 did the trick for me finally.

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact error in `zsh` and `MacVim`, and eventually tracked it back to [this RVM issue.](https://rvm.io/integration/vim/) The solution was to move the RVM sourcing I had in `.zshrc` to `.zshenv`. Worked immediately. Just posting on the off chance someone stumbles across this the way I did.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with zsh, rvm and vim.

The latest solution is to set the shell to sh in your .vimrc

```
set shell=sh
```

[This blog](http://gabebw.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/rails-vim-rvm-and-a-curious-infuriating-bug/) has all the solutions listed