# Rake giving weird error when run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

```
rake db:create
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0035 p:-17564094817632 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 TOP   
c:0034 p:---- s:0106 b:0106 l:000105 d:000105 CFUNC  :require
c:0033 p:0029 s:0102 b:0102 l:000098 d:000101 BLOCK  /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
c:0032 p:0035 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 TOP    /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:2
c:0031 p:---- s:0097 b:0097 l:000096 d:000096 FINISH
c:0030 p:---- s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 CFUNC  :require
c:0029 p:0026 s:0091 b:0091 l:000072 d:000090 BLOCK  /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0028 p:---- s:0088 b:0088 l:000087 d:000087 FINISH
c:0027 p:---- s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 CFUNC  :each
c:0026 p:0091 s:0083 b:0083 l:000072 d:000082 BLOCK  /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0025 p:---- s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 FINISH
c:0024 p:---- s:0076 b:0076 l:000075 d:000075 CFUNC  :each
c:0023 p:0046 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0022 p:0021 s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122
c:0021 p:0089 s:0065 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 TOP    /Users/tjstalcup/rails/blog/config/application.rb:7
c:0020 p:---- s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 FINISH
c:0019 p:---- s:0061 b:0061 l:000060 d:000060 CFUNC  :require
c:0018 p:0053 s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
c:0017 p:0026 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 TOP    /Users/tjstalcup/rails/blog/Rakefile:5
c:0016 p:---- s:0048 b:0048 l:000047 d:000047 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0046 b:0046 l:000045 d:000045 CFUNC  :load
c:0014 p:0013 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25
c:0013 p:0274 s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495
c:0012 p:0009 s:0033 b:0033 l:000026 d:000032 BLOCK  /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78
c:0011 p:0009 s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129
c:0010 p:0011 s:0027 b:0027 l:000026 d:000026 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77
c:0009 p:0019 s:0024 b:0024 l:000017 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61
c:0008 p:0009 s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129
c:0007 p:0011 s:0018 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 METHOD /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59
c:0006 p:0048 s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 TOP    /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
c:0005 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0127 s:0007 b:0007 l:0005a8 d:000130 EVAL   /Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0005a8 d:0005a8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/tjstalcup/rails/blog/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/tjstalcup/rails/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/tjstalcup/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068005/random-segmentation-fault-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-0-9

Comment: I do not have prawn installed as of yet

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423471/rails-segmentation-fault-when-starting-server

Comment: Thanks brick, from those links and just messing around, it turns out it was an issue w/ the sqlite3 gem, so i just removed it and then re-installed, and it's golden now.  Thanks again.