# Michael Hartl Tutorial Chapter 6: Error bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've followed the guide which is excellent, however, when I add has_secure_password to my user model:
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
      has_secure_password

```
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

and then try to add a user via the rails console:

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > User.create(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com",
1.9.3-p125 :002 >     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

I receive a very lengthy error message that starts with:

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0058 p:-17575139500290 s:0220 b:0220 l:000219 d:000219 TOP   
c:0057 p:---- s:0218 b:0218 l:000217 d:000217 CFUNC  :require
```

and continues for many more lines...

If I take out "has_secure_password" from user.rb and try to create the same user as above I receive the following error:

```
 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: password
```

Finally, if I then insert "attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation" into the model I can successfully add the user, however, the password_digest is nil.

I know I'm doing something wrong, however, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CFUNC  :require

You see - this is the root of the problem

there is similar problem [problem with CFUNC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423471/rails-segmentation-fault-when-starting-server)

Most likely, the problem is not in code, but in rails(some parts are using different versions of it) or in gems.
I recommend reinstall your environment and check, that everything correspons tutorial.

For example, it important to set gems such versions, that are in tutorial, even if there are new versions now.