# Segmentation fault on Rails sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm starting learning Ruby on Rails using RubyMine.
I tried Ruby 2 and Rails 4 version and when I run debug I get this segmentation fault message.
I can't find the crash report file in the suggested paths.
How can I solve it?

```
/Users/giacomorebonato/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/giacomorebonato/RubymineProjects/MinoDemo/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/Users/giacomorebonato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.
```

Comment: If you use mac and upgrade recently to OS Sierra, maybe this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812707/segmentation-fault-with-rails-after-upgrading-to-os-sierra-possibly-related-to

Answer (score 3):

~ should be your home directory.  In CMD, enter "env", HOME should likely be /C/Users/giacomorebonato/.

What package did you use to install Ruby?  Railsinstaller seems to be the most common, however I use BitNami Rubystack with Rubymine and it works very well.  However, I converted to MySQL just out of personal preference of its GUI.

Try to run the app in the package's CMD interface outside of Rubymine.  Is the problem specific to Rubymine?  If so, you can check with [JetBrains Support Page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home).  Serge is fantastic.

In any case, segment faults using sqlite3 are relatively common.  Search in SO and you'll find many occurrences and potential solutions.  The most common issue seems to be the need to reinstall sqlite3:

```
gem uninstall sqlite3
gem install sqlite3
```

Also, check your versions of ruby, rails and rake.

```
ruby -v
rails -v
rake --version
```

to see if you are getting what you are expecting.  Often, configuration problems cause unexpected mixtures.

Are you using PIK?

Do you have multiple Ruby installations on your system?  Run:

```
where ruby
```

Searching SO, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423471/rails-segmentation-fault-when-starting-server).  It discusses many causes and solutions.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is specific to RubyMine (on command line it's all fine).

Comment: Glad to help if you can answer my questions.  What Ruby package did you install?  Are you using PIK?  Do you have more than one Ruby installed?  Is this problem new or has debug run successfully in the past?  What version of Rubymine are you running?  Under Rubymine, do you have settings/Ruby SDK and Gems set appropriately?  Did you find the crash files?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote on Jetbrains support forum and Serge answered very fast.
The Ruby version used by RubyMine was different from the console one.
I reinstalled Ruby with RVM and I setup console to use the right Ruby version.