# Segmentation fault with Rails after upgrading to OS Sierra, possibly related to sqlite3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby, ruby-2.3

After upgrading to OSX Sierra I am having an issue with random segmentation faults. It most commonly occurs when running rails test and I believe it is due to the sqlite3_adapter.

My present work around is to simply quit terminal and restart it. This works for about 1 or 2 rails test and by the third one I am almost guaranteed to get another segmentation fault.

Is anybody else having an issue with this or find a better workaround?

```
$ rails t
Running via Spring preloader in process 13817
/Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

**Edit**:

After digging into the sqlite3_adapter.rb, I see that the line causing the segmentation fault is the creation of a new SQlite3 database.

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new(
    config[:database].to_s,
    :results_as_hash => true
)
```

**Edit 2**:

Rather than quitting and restarting terminal, I have found that running:

```
spring stop
```

stops the problem temporarily. Not a solution, but a better work around.

**Edit 3**:

This appears to be a problem with Apple's supplied libsqlite3 not being fork safe. More info can be found here:

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/195

For now, I have created an alias at the bottom of my ~/.bashrc file:

```
alias ss='spring stop'
```

When the problem occurs, I can now type:

```
ss
```

and then rerun the test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a patch has been issued! The patch will look for sqlite3 in your brew folder instead of using Apple's supplied version by default. Simply run:

```
bundle update
```

to get the latest version of sqlite3-ruby and if you don't already have sqlite3 installed in your homebrew directory, run:

```
brew install sqlite3
```

Comment: this worked for me.  If you get a "This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local" message, I ignored it without having an issue.

Comment: Just a quick note to say this is the exact sequence of commands that worked for me: `brew install sqlite3; gem uninstall sqlite3; bundle update`.

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. I have run this several times as well as `gem pristine sqlite3` and still nothing works. I am running ruby 2.3.3. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Do you have homebrew installed? What do you see when you run    brew list

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when upgrading to Sierra. A simple **`bundle update`** will do the trick! Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked temporarily but it looks like the problem is back. :(

Comment: @Hutch Same thing happened here.

Comment: It helped me, macOS Sierra

Answer (score 2):

Try rebuilding the sqlite3 gem. It has native extensions, and recompiling them in the Sierra environment may fix the issue.

Run:

```
gem pristine sqlite3
```

Which should give output like:

```
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Restored sqlite3-1.3.10
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Restored sqlite3-1.3.11
```

Comment: That didn't do it. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the sqlite3 gem as well. No luck.

Comment: This was the last step needed after installing `sqlite3` from Homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that I get a segfault as well, when trying to run rails console --sandbox specifically. I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651519/error-while-installing-nokogiri-1-6-7-on-el-capitan) that seemed to fix this issue; specifically running

```
xcode-select --install
```

seemed to resolve it. This is by no means scientifically proven yet, however I am now able to run a rails console and all tests without a ruby segment fault.

Comment: Tried that and I'm just getting they are already installed. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem w/Sierra.  None of the stuff on this page worked for me, i.e. `gem pristine sqlite3`, `xcode-select --install`, `sqlite3; gem uninstall sqlite3; bundle update`.  I eventually completely uninstalled the Ruby version with `rbenv uninstall 2.3.1`, then reinstalled it. This worked. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I upgraded sqlite3 gem to 1.3.12 and it helped

Comment: after editing gem file, it is required to run bundle install

Answer (score 0):

All the previous solutions didn't worked so I've fixed this way:

`gem uninstall sqlite3`

`brew install sqlite3`

`gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.15.2/include --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.15.2/lib`

(Check the version you have in Cellar)

This is a temporary fix and probably if update the bundle it will stop working and you will do it again but al least I can work on my machine