# got this bug in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Got this error in rails 5.0.0.1 in ruby 2.3.1 while creating a post with title.
I have already submitted the full error in ruby bug reporter site. Getting this problem frequently.I tried formatting sierra and then installing it again. Still getting this error.

```
Nischals-Device:jwt_api_auth nischalgautam$ rails c 
Running via Spring preloader in process 23900
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
2.3.1 :001 > @post=Post.create(title: "hello")
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter                                         
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter                                          
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0063 p:---- s:0262 e:000261 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0062 p:---- s:0260 e:000259 CFUNC  :new
c:0061 p:0183 s:0255 e:000254 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27
c:0060 p:0028 s:0248 e:000247 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_p
c:0059 p:0027 s:0245 e:000244 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_p
c:0058 p:0025 s:0242 e:000241 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_p
c:0057 p:0018 s:0237 e:000236 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_p
c:0056 p:0016 s:0232 e:000230 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_p
c:0055 p:0035 s:0227 e:000223 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_p
c:0054 p:0046 s:0221 e:000220 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_p
c:0053 p:0015 s:0215 e:000214 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128
c:0052 p:0008 s:0212 e:000211 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91
c:0051 p:0008 s:0209 e:000208 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:354
c:0050 p:0010 s:0206 e:000205 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:233
c:0049 p:0010 s:0203 e:000202 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:28
c:0048 p:0019 s:0200 e:000199 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:349
c:0047 p:0008 s:0197 e:000196 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:266
c:0046 p:0008 s:0194 e:000193 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:179
c:0045 p:0062 s:0190 e:000189 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:54
c:0044 p:0042 s:0183 e:000182 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33
c:0043 p:0014 s:0177 e:000176 EVAL   (irb):1 [FINISH]
c:0042 p:---- s:0175 e:000174 CFUNC  :eval
c:0041 p:0025 s:0168 e:000167 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/workspace.rb:87
c:0040 p:0027 s:0161 e:000159 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/context.rb:380
c:0039 p:0024 s:0155 e:000154 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:489
c:0038 p:0041 s:0147 e:000146 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:623
c:0037 p:0011 s:0142 e:000141 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:486
c:0036 p:0128 s:0138 e:000137 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246 [FINISH]
c:0035 p:---- s:0135 e:000134 CFUNC  :loop
c:0034 p:0009 s:0132 e:000131 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232 [FINISH]
c:0033 p:---- s:0130 e:000129 CFUNC  :catch
c:0032 p:0018 s:0126 e:000125 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231
c:0031 p:0037 s:0123 E:001c40 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:485
c:0030 p:0009 s:0120 e:000119 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:395 [FINISH]
c:0029 p:---- s:0118 e:000117 CFUNC  :catch
c:0028 p:0174 s:0114 E:0004f0 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:394
c:0027 p:0160 s:0109 E:001c20 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65
c:0026 p:0015 s:0106 E:000538 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9
c:0025 p:0101 s:0102 E:000588 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78
c:0024 p:0036 s:0098 E:0005d8 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49
c:0023 p:0127 s:0094 E:000630 TOP    /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18 [FINISH]
c:0022 p:---- s:0090 e:000089 CFUNC  :require
c:0021 p:0012 s:0086 E:0006c0 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293
c:0020 p:0057 s:0084 E:000740 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259
c:0019 p:0017 s:0079 E:000680 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293
c:0018 p:0063 s:0074 E:000798 TOP    /Users/nischalgautam/Desktop/lang/ruby/railsprojects/jwt_api_auth/bin/rails:9 [FINISH]
c:0017 p:---- s:0071 e:000070 CFUNC  :load
c:0016 p:0014 s:0066 E:001680 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287
c:0015 p:0057 s:0064 E:001700 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259
c:0014 p:0021 s:0059 E:001638 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287
c:0013 p:0056 s:0053 E:001750 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6
c:0012 p:0024 s:0050 E:001790 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38
c:0011 p:0204 s:0047 E:001860 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:191 [FINISH]
c:0010 p:---- s:0045 e:000044 CFUNC  :fork
c:0009 p:0272 s:0042 E:001820 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161
c:0008 p:0075 s:0029 E:0018e0 BLOCK  /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0027 e:000026 CFUNC  :loop
c:0006 p:0028 s:0024 E:0018a0 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125
c:0005 p:0167 s:0021 E:0008e8 TOP    /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19 [FINISH]
c:0004 p:---- s:0018 e:000017 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0124 s:0014 E:001988 METHOD /Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0002 p:0008 s:0004 E:001be0 EVAL   -e:1 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:001cf0 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
-e:1:in `<main>'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/Users/nischalgautam/Desktop/lang/ruby/railsprojects/jwt_api_auth/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:394:in `start'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:394:in `catch'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:395:in `block in start'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:485:in `eval_input'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `each_top_level_statement'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `catch'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `loop'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:486:in `block in eval_input'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/context.rb:380:in `evaluate'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/workspace.rb:87:in `evaluate'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/workspace.rb:87:in `eval'
(irb):1:in `irb_binding'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:54:in `new'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:179:in `has_attribute?'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:266:in `attribute_types'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:349:in `load_schema'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:28:in `load_schema!'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:233:in `load_schema!'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:354:in `load_schema!'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:875:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:501:in `checkout'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:705:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:744:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:765:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:721:in `new_connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27:in `sqlite3_connection'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27:in `new'
/Users/nischalgautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27:in `initialize'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 rax: 0x0000000000000100 rbx: 0x00007fffc376b430 rcx: 0x0000000000000000
 rdx: 0x0000000000000000 rdi: 0x00007fffc37ce1c0 rsi: 0x00007f9064f97e40
 rbp: 0x00007fff5d4be0d0 rsp: 0x00007fff5d4be088  r8: 0x00000000a40008ff
  r9: 0x00000000ffffffff r10: 0x0000000100000000 r11: 0x0000000000000000
 r12: 0x00007fffc37696d0 r13: 0x0000000000000000 r14: 0x00007f9062664990
 r15: 0x00007f9062664b58 rip: 0x00007fffbaae8943 rfl: 0x0000000000010206

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e8a44 rb_vm_bugreport + 388
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102783c8a rb_bug_context + 490
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102858a54 sigsegv + 68
3   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fffbad15bba _sigtramp + 26
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffbaae8943 _dispatch_queue_push + 171
5   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffba6b2d78 fillInUnixFile + 568
6   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffba6b29b0 unixOpen + 2192
7   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffba6ae7f8 sqlite3BtreeOpen + 2856
8   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffba6aa761 openDatabase + 1169
9   sqlite3_native.bundle               0x00000001035bf802 initialize + 962
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e5844 vm_call0_body + 532
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e60dd rb_call0 + 397
12  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001027e5a99 rb_class_new_instance + 41
13  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
14  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c94ac vm_exec_core + 10220
15  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
16  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e6d95 eval_string_with_cref + 1605
17  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d53f1 rb_f_eval + 161
18  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
19  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c94ac vm_exec_core + 10220
20  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
21  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e7180 loop_i + 48
22  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x000000010278d358 rb_rescue2 + 280
23  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
24  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c92b8 vm_exec_core + 9720
25  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
26  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e7117 catch_i + 87
27  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d65eb rb_catch_protect + 155
28  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d6e4c rb_f_catch + 76
29  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
30  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c92b8 vm_exec_core + 9720
31  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
32  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e7117 catch_i + 87
33  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d65eb rb_catch_protect + 155
34  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d6e4c rb_f_catch + 76
35  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
36  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c92b8 vm_exec_core + 9720
37  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
38  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102790430 rb_load_internal0 + 288
39  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102790cf5 rb_require_internal + 1829
40  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001027904b8 rb_f_require + 24
41  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
42  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c9715 vm_exec_core + 10837
43  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
44  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102790430 rb_load_internal0 + 288
45  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x000000010279129f rb_f_load + 159
46  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
47  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c9715 vm_exec_core + 10837
48  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
49  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d4bf7 rb_yield + 183
50  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x000000010278d59a rb_protect + 250
51  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102810e2d rb_f_fork + 93
52  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
53  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c92b8 vm_exec_core + 9720
54  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
55  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028e7180 loop_i + 48
56  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x000000010278d358 rb_rescue2 + 280
57  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
58  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c92b8 vm_exec_core + 9720
59  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
60  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102790430 rb_load_internal0 + 288
61  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000102790cf5 rb_require_internal + 1829
62  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001027904b8 rb_f_require + 24
63  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028ded4a vm_call_cfunc + 314
64  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028c94ac vm_exec_core + 10220
65  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x00000001028d9583 vm_exec + 131
66  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x000000010278c708 ruby_exec_internal + 152
67  libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x000000010278c616 ruby_run_node + 54
68  ruby                                0x000000010273bf2f main + 79
```

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812707/segmentation-fault-with-rails-after-upgrading-to-os-sierra-possibly-related-to

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: its similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812707/segmentation-fault-with-rails-after-upgrading-to-os-sierra-possibly-related-to
Solved now Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All the answer in [Segmentation fault with Rails after upgrading to OS Sierra, possibly related to sqlite3 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812707/segmentation-fault-with-rails-after-upgrading-to-os-sierra-possibly-related-to)  didn't worked with me so I've fixed this way:

`gem uninstall sqlite3`

`brew install sqlite3`

`gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.15.2/include --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.15.2/lib`

(Check the version you have in Cellar)

This is a temporary fix and probably if update the bundle it will stop working and you will do it again but al least I can work on my machine