# My Rails Console keeps crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, console, rails-console

I have a problem with my Rails Console, it keeps crashing and I can't figure out why. For example, when I type the following

```
rails c
Category.connection
```

It begins with the following error:

```
/Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Then it gives the a whole lot of error messages, with more than 1500 lines with my gemsfiles listed.

I hope someone can help me to fix this problem, by the way I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.1

When anyone needs additional information, please let me know because I don't know what I should include for someone to recognize the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defect is in sqlite3 gem.. its here

[https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12781 and https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12795](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12781%20and%20https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12795)

Try using

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
```

Comment: I already fixed it, it seems that when you use the "gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'", it will work, at least for me.

Comment: @Arend At that time I had changed the database, as yo are saying its working with this version then its good news

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with mac os sierra and sqlite3. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948143/2509777), basiclly you should run `bundle update` and `brew install sqlite3`