# Ruby on Rails – Crashes on Rails Generate Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, model, rubygems

Rails newbie here, and I'm trying to generate a model using `rails generate model`. The command I used is exactly `rails generate model testmodel name:string`, and I got the ridiculously long error below. I'm sorry for the extremely vague question, but I have no idea what to make of this.

I really don't know what to make of it, but I'm assuming it's a problem with the `sqlite` gem.

Has anyone had this problem before?

```
Fares:project_name faresalaboud$ rails generate model testmodel name:string
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0017 p:-17588820269308 s:0059 e:000058 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0016 p:---- s:0057 e:000056 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0020 s:0053 e:000052 BLOCK  /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
c:0014 p:0032 s:0050 e:000049 TOP    /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0048 e:000047 CFUNC  :require
c:0012 p:0037 s:0044 e:000043 BLOCK  /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0011 p:---- s:0041 e:000040 CFUNC  :each
c:0010 p:0055 s:0038 e:000037 BLOCK  /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
c:0009 p:---- s:0031 e:000030 CFUNC  :each
c:0008 p:0030 s:0028 e:000027 METHOD /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
c:0007 p:0013 s:0024 e:000023 METHOD /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132
c:0006 p:0047 s:0020 e:000019 TOP    /Users/faresalaboud/rails_projects/alfaris_guests/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0018 e:000017 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0289 s:0014 e:000013 TOP    /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:43 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require
c:0002 p:0034 s:0004 E:002478 EVAL   bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:001198 TOP    [FINISH]

bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
/Users/faresalaboud/rails_projects/alfaris_guests/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x000000010b99b303 rb_print_backtrace + 29
1   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x000000010b99b3ea rb_vm_bugreport + 124
2   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x000000010b8a5aa3 report_bug + 285
3   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x000000010b8a5981 rb_bug + 179
4   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x000000010b93ddbe check_stack_overflow + 0
5   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff9304c5aa _sigtramp + 26
6   libruby.2.0.0.dylib                 0x000000010bfa543a ruby_xmalloc + 26
7   ???                                 0x00007ff9bb12dd80 0x0 + 140710562160000

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/rbconfig.rb
    4 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    5 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    6 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    8 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/version.rb
    9 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   10 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   11 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   12 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   13 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   14 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   15 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   16 thread.rb
   17 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/thread.bundle
   18 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb
   19 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   20 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
   21 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/pathname.bundle
   22 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/pathname.rb
   23 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/constants.rb
   24 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   25 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/etc.bundle
   26 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
   27 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   28 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
   29 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   30 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
   31 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb
   32 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
   33 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   34 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   35 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   36 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/version.rb
   37 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb
   38 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb
   39 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   40 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/digest.bundle
   41 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/digest.rb
   42 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/digest/sha1.bundle
   43 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/set.rb
   44 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb
   45 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
   46 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
   47 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
   48 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source.rb
   49 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb
   50 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb
   51 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/ftp.rb
   52 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/http.rb
   53 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/https.rb
   54 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/ldap.rb
   55 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   56 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/mailto.rb
   57 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri.rb
   58 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/socket.bundle
   59 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb
   60 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb
   61 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb
   62 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/zlib.bundle
   63 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/stringio.bundle
   64 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/exceptions.rb
   65 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb
   66 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
   67 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/request.rb
   68 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/requests.rb
   69 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb
   70 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/responses.rb
   71 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/proxy_delta.rb
   72 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/backward.rb
   73 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb
   74 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/date_core.bundle
   75 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/date/format.rb
   76 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/date.rb
   77 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/time.rb
   78 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request.rb
   79 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/cgi/core.rb
   80 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/cgi/util.rb
   81 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/cgi/cookie.rb
   82 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/cgi.rb
   83 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/uri_formatter.rb
   84 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/fcntl.bundle
   85 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
   86 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/bn.rb
   87 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/cipher.rb
   88 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/config.rb
   89 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/digest.rb
   90 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/x509.rb
   91 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb
   92 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/ssl.rb
   93 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb
   94 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/securerandom.rb
   95 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb
   96 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
   97 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/text.rb
   98 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
   99 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
  100 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
  101 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/strscan.bundle
  102 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
  103 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
  104 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
  105 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
  106 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb
  107 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/forwardable.rb
  108 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
  109 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb
  110 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
  111 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/index.rb
  112 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
  113 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
  114 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
  115 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb
  116 /Users/faresalaboud/rails_projects/alfaris_guests/config/boot.rb
  117 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/version.rb
  118 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/delegate.rb
  119 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/synchronized_delegator.rb
  120 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe.rb
  121 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append.rb
  122 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb
  123 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb
  124 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb
  125 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/version.rb
  126 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb
  127 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb
  128 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n.rb
  129 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb
  130 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/config.rb
  131 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/i18n.rb
  132 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/non_concurrent_cache_backend.rb
  133 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/mri_cache_backend.rb
  134 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb
  135 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb
  136 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/inflections.rb
  137 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb
  138 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb
  139 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/version.rb
  140 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb
  141 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb
  142 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/concern.rb
  143 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb
  144 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb
  145 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/logger.rb
  146 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support.rb
  147 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb
  148 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class.rb
  149 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors.rb
  150 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/multibyte.rb
  151 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte.rb
  152 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb
  153 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb
  154 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb
  155 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/core_ext/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb
  156 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/core_ext/ordered_hash.rb
  157 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/error.rb
  158 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb
  159 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/parser/argument.rb
  160 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/parser/arguments.rb
  161 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/parser/option.rb
  162 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb
  163 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/parser.rb
  164 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb
  165 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/line_editor/basic.rb
  166 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/readline.bundle
  167 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb
  168 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/line_editor.rb
  169 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/util.rb
  170 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb
  171 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb
  172 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb
  173 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb
  174 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/core_ext/io_binary_read.rb
  175 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb
  176 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb
  177 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_link.rb
  178 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/directory.rb
  179 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/erb.rb
  180 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb
  181 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb
  182 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb
  183 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/generators/base.rb
  184 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/generators.rb
  185 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/ruby_version_check.rb
  186 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb
  187 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb
  188 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb
  189 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb
  190 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb
  191 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/singleton.rb
  192 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb
  193 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb
  194 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb
  195 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mutex_m.rb
  196 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb
  197 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/per_thread_registry.rb
  198 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb
  199 /Users/faresalaboud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/deprecation/behaviors.rb
  ....

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Searched around and I think you will find luck [on this other stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375709/1484701%20here). I was about to suggest a more radical move - a complete uninstall of rvm and rails, and reinstalling, but start here first.

If you can't do other rails commands like

```
rails console
```

then you will probably have to go this route:

Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747195/1484701) to nuke your rvm install. And make sure you're following the official rvm install guide [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

Comment: Thanks! `rails console` crashes, the same way this does. I guess I'll do that.

Comment: Updating my link for instructions on nuking your rails install and starting over. If it helps you, please mark it accepted - best of luck!