# Rails s command gives Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.2

If i run **rails s** i am getting this error

```
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle: [BUG] 
Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000440
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin16]

Abort trap: 6
```

Versions

ruby

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

rails

```
rails 3.2.22
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails segmentation fault when starting server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423471/rails-segmentation-fault-when-starting-server)

Comment: Information about OS (Mac OS x ...) and Database (Postgres ...) would be nice, too.

Comment: Try this: http://www.odysseyonrails.com/articles/1

Comment: it didn't work for me, my os is mac 10.12.3, postgres gem 9.6

Comment: Fixed this issue, after uninstall all rvm, all ruby and all, just cleanup my rails